# Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

To clarify my question the original problem is that I was trying to :

I don't know the problem with this code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    String date = "Sep 13, 2016 6:16:46 PM";
    Date parse = fromFormat.parse(date);
```

I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sep 13, 2016 6:16:46 PM"
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: "set" -- perhaps you meant "sep"?

Comment: @larsgrefer i wanna parse a Date from one format to another.

Comment: @RickJames thats another problem, i´m recieving a date from a rest api on "sep" ( ETC timezone ) format and i need to parse to "set" (BRT timezone). I tried to set timezones but i got the same exception.

Comment: Please clarify in your question what you are really trying to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all!

I found the error:

My default locale is incompatible with the input date. So I need to set the Locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
    String date = "Sep 13, 2016 6:16:46 PM";
    Date parse = fromFormat.parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my IDE,I haven't got your error,but met with this

```
    Date parse = toFormat.parse(formated);
```

error found:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type ParseException
```

Maybe our java versions is different.
for Class SimpleDateFormat, I got reference to JAVA API according to my JAVA version. 
It is the the lack of parameter that resulted in the error I faced.

[as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMprl.png)

Comment: not to throws ParseException,try to fix you parameter  refer to api.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` instances use different patterns, so the second instance can not parse a date formatted by the first one